# Time to absorption for infinite state Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain with a single absorbing state $s_{-1}$. The transient states have absorption probabilities $p_{i,-1} = 1-f_i$ and transition probabilities to the next state $p_{i,i+1} = f_i$. We also have that the starting state is $s_0$. I want to find the expected absorbing time. I've calculated something that looks somewhat reasonable, but I suspect that even if I didn't make a mistake somewhere, there is some easier way of doing this. The problem is of course that it has infinitely many states and the probability changes with the states.

Let $s_i = 1$ indicate we are at the absorbing state at iteration $i$. Then the time to absorption can be written as

$$E[\tau] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i P(s_i=1,s_{i-1}=0) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i P(s_i = 1|s_{i-1} = 0)P(s_{i-1}=0) 
= \sum_{i=1}^\infty i(1-f_{i-1})P(s_{i-1}=0),$$

but $P(s_{i-1} = 0) = P(s_{i-2} = 0)f_{i-2} = P(s_{i-3}=0)f_{i-2}f_{i-3} = \dots = P(s_1 = 0)\prod_{n=1}^{i-1} f_{i-n}$, and $P(s_i = 0) = 1$, so $P(s_{i-1} = 0) = \prod_{n=1}^{i-1}f_{i-n}$. Plugging in above we get

$$E[\tau] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i (1-f_{i-1})\prod_{n=1}^{i-1}f_{i-n}.$$

This looks rather ugly of course. Can it be done more elegantly?

(PS. In my special case, we have $f_i = \binom{k+i+1}{k-1}^{-1}$ which of course goes to zero quite fast, causing the absorption probability $1-f_i$ to go to 1 quite fast as well.)

Comment: What is the absorbing state here, 0? I ask because you don't tell us $p_{0,0}=1$ in the general part of the question, nor do you say that the process is stopped upon hitting zero, or anything.

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy notation, will try to edit. Why don't we call the absorbing state $s_{-1}$ or something then since $s_0$ is reserved for the starting state.

Comment: I guess it should also be $s_i = i$ if it is not absorbing and $s_i = -1$ if it is. Is it clear what I meant at least?

Comment: Your notation is still not clear.  What is meant by $P[s_{i-1}=0]$?  Do you intend $i$ to be a time index, or a state index?

Comment: The probability that at time instant $i-1$, we have not reached the absorbing state.

Comment: Or do you really mean $P[s_{i-1}=0]$ is the probability that the Markov chain is in state 0 at time $i-1$?

Comment: In any case, it looks like you are computing the probability that we get absorbed at time $k$, which seems to be $f_0f_1...f_{k-2}(1-f_{k-1})$ (assuming we start in state 0, and depending on the notational interpretations).  Another way to solve is to define $m_i$ as the average time to absorption, given we start in state $i$, and write a linear reecurrence relation for $m_i$.

Comment: Another way is to define $X_i$ as an indicator function that is 1 if we are not yet absorbed after hop $i$ (and zero else).   If $\tau$ is the total time to absorption, then $$\tau = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$$ and $E[\tau] = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[X_i]$.